# CSS Grid. Грид-интервалы

Tags: css, html5, css-grid

Код:

```css
.grid_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  border: 1px solid #be3144;
}

button {
  height: 65px;
  width: 80px;
  color: white;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  border: none;
  background: #4d4d4d;
  font-family: Share Tech Mono, monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_container">
  <button id="1" value="1">1</button>
  <button id="2" value="2">2</button>
  <button id="3" value="3">3</button>
  <button id="4" value="4">4</button>
  <button id="5" value="5">5</button>
  <button id="6" value="6">6</button>
  <button id="7" value="7">7</button>
  <button id="8" value="8">8</button>
  <button id="9" value="9">9</button>
  <button id="10" value="10">10</button>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что расстояние между колонками где-то 20px, хотя по-умолчанию  его быть не должно.
Я пытался его убрать или изменить с помощью свойств `grid-column-gap:2px;` и `grid-gap`, но не получается.
Вопрос, откуда взялись эти интервалы и как от них избавиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button {
  width: 98px;
}
```

тогда отступ станет 2рх

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Ну всё правильно. Вы указали свойством `grid-template-columns` ширину 1 столбца равным **100px**. А элементам, помещённым в эти столбцы, ширину в **80px**. Эти **20px** и составляют отступ

Comment: Спасибо, нигде не видел этой информации